# Azure B2C user migration confusing demo code

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Why is it that within [this file](https://github.com/yoelhor/Azure-AD-B2C-UserMigration/blob/master/AADB2C.UserMigration/Program.cs) from the Azure B2C migration example, the `MigrateUsersWithRandomPasswordAsync` method calls both:

```
'b2CGraphClient.CreateAccount()'
```

and

```
table.Execute(insertOperation);
```

While the method right above it `MigrateUsersWithPasswordAsync()` that almost does the exact same thing only calls:

```
b2CGraphClient.CreateAccount()
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought about deleting this question but I'll leave in here just in case.  If I would have kept reading the tutorial [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration) on how to migrate users I would have found the answer.

Basically it can be summed up in this paragraph from the tutorial:

> To track the password change, you use an Azure table. When you run the
>   pre-migration process with the command-line parameter 2, you create a
>   user entity in an Azure table. Your service does the following:
>
> - On sign-in, the Azure AD B2C policy invokes your migration RESTful
>     service, sending an email message as an input claim. The service
>     searches for the email address in the Azure table. If the address
>     exists, the service throws an error message: You must change password.
> - After the user successfully changes the password, remove the entity
>     from the Azure table.

For anyone that might still have lingering questions I'll belabor:

When migrating users with a temporary password you need to configure the user with a hard to crack random password so that while these new accounts are in B2C they can't be hacked.  This temporary random password is not a password you'll ever send to the user, it's just used to protect the account.

At the same time the user is added to the B2C accounts, you also need to add an entry into a new Azure table called "users" that that simply contains the users login id (meaning they need to change their password).  Later you'll use a custom signin policy that will check this table to see if the user exists in this table.  If so, they will be sent a custom message telling them to change their password and a link is provided.  It's actually the same procedure as the "forgot password" where is uses the user's email to help them change their password.

After the user changes their password their entry in the new Azure table will be removed signifying that they have changed their password and they will no longer receive the message to change their password.